# Devise registration for with nested entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms

I'm building a Rails app where User can have more Addresses.

```
User has_many :addresses
Address belong_to :user
```

I'm using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication. I want an User entity and first Address entity to be created by one form when the user is registering.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %><br />
  <%= t.password_field :password %><br />

  <%= f.fields_for resource.addresses do |a| %>
    <%= a.text_field :street %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But I'm getting

*undefined method 'street' for ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []*

what must be done in controller?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have already in the User model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
```

And I have updated my controller like this:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    # super
    build_resource({})
    yield resource if block_given?
    resource.addresses.build
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

and view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %><br />
  <%= t.password_field :password %><br />

  <%= f.fields_for resource.addresses.first do |a| %>
  <%= a.text_field :street %>
<% end %>
```

So the form is displaying. But when I post, the `resource.addresses.first` is still null:

*undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add accepts_nested_attributes_for addresses

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

You also need to initialise the address object, You can do this at controller level (Best Approach) or at view

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %><br />
  <%= t.password_field :password %><br />
  <% resource.addresses.build %>
  <%= f.fields_for resource.addresses do |a| %>
    <%= a.text_field :street %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And you need to add the corresponding to the parameters that you are receiving at your controller.

Comment: This is the answer! I would add the controller code though, since he did ask for controller code specifically.

Comment: Hi, I have already `accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses`.
See my update above pls

Comment: Have you initialised the address object